# Postman launches with a blank screen

Tags: postman

This is now the third or fourth time that this has happened in the last couple of weeks: When I launch Postman all I get is a blank screen:

[image: Postman blank screen]

The only way to get around this that I have found is to reboot my workstation, which is of course a PITA.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, 7.20.0.

Any fixes, workarounds etc are welcomed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had same problem on my linux machine. Simply run the following on your terminal until they both tell you no more process to kill.

```sh
killall Postman
killall _Postman
```

Comment: I imagine you meant `killall` for the first call?

Comment: Somehow.. had to run above commands 2 times, then postman got running !

Answer (score 6):

I started facing this issue on updating to version - v8.2.3,

Try below approach, which worked for me..

Step 1: Add windows environment variable: **POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU**, with the value: **true**

Step 2: From the same blank screen open a New Postman Window (File -> New Postman Window)

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me, I had to go to "System Monitor" and kill a load of processes with names like "postman --no-sandbox", "postman --type=zygote".

Comment: This worked for me. Just run `ps eux | grep postman` and you see all those processes and you can kill them.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the previous answer, I put a script together that performs the loop as many times as needed to get Postman working again:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT=$(killall Postman 2>&1)

while [ "$OUTPUT" != "Postman: no process found" ]; do
    OUTPUT=$(killall Postman 2>&1)
done

OUTPUT=$(killall _Postman 2>&1)

while [ "$OUTPUT" != "_Postman: no process found" ]; do
    OUTPUT=$(killall _Postman 2>&1)
done
```

Make sure you set the permission for the file correctly so you can execute it:

`chmod 700 kill_all_postman_procs.sh`

To run it:

`./kill_all_postman_procs.sh` or may you need to do `sudo ./kill_all_postman_procs.sh`

Answer (score 2):

It's all about GPU driver and setting, it may happen when you don't force disable that setting and running on dual monitor.

On windows 10, to disable it you can disable it from gpu control panel, POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU, or try to run postman before plugging the 2nd monitor

Answer (score 1):

FOr all options listed above failed to work. My os is `Ubuntu 18`. The only solution was to install a version that worked. Before you install this version uninstall the currently installed afterwards install this snap version

```
snap install --channel=v7/stable postman
```

If you have this specific version installed. run the following

```
snap refresh --channel=v7/stable postman
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue came up overnight for me. I resolved this issue by just reinstalling Postman. It kept all my settings and collections. You might like this quick way instead of fiddling with settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to this - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9193 and figuring out that issue is not fixed for 2 years, I recommend switching to another tool, like advanced rest client from google.

Answer (score 0):

For me (after updating from v10.11 to 10.12) i was able to resolve the "blank tabs" issue by clearing the cache and reloading. This can be done via the help menu as follows -

[image]

This behaviour also occurred on a Windows 10 install and not Linux.

Comment: I signed out and back in, which I believe clears the cache (so basically what you done), and it seemed to fix the issue for me on Linux.